# Enable Google Login for Communities

Tags: oauth2, community, google

in my developer org i have set up a community. I also have set up google as auth provider. The auth process is working great for sales cloud users.

Speaking of community users there is the problem, that they get redirected to the mydomain login page instead of the community login page. --> community users can't login via the mydomain login page.

Anyone knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. I just forgot to add the community parameter to the 'link existing account' URL:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_addl_params_community.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_addl_params_community